# XML LOading through script

Tags: xml, apache-pig

I have an XML which which is loaded through Pig script and can be read through Hive as well.

The above process is working if i have values in all tags like
val1val2  but if my file looks like

val1/TAG2>  ( no value present for TAG2 then nothing is written in output)
How can i correct this

Comment: Please elaborate your problem by showing the scripts and XML data you have.

Comment: XML 1 :--> <HEADER><TAG1>AAAAAAA</TAG1><TAG2>ZZZZZZZ</TAG2></HEADER>

XML2 :- --> <HEADER><TAG1>AAAAAAA</TAG1></TAG2></HEADER>

REGISTER piggybank.jar
A =  LOAD '/test.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('HEADER') as (x:chararray);
B = foreach A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(x,'<HEADER>\\s*<TAG1>(.*)</TAG1><TAG2>(.*)</TAG2><HEADER>'))
As (TAG1:chararray,
TAG2:chararray)
;
store B  into '/output '   using PigStorage('|') ;

If XML1 is input then data is loaded correctly, If XML2 is used as Input then nothing gets loaded.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the scripts and XML data with proper formatting (see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). It's difficult to read the content of the scripts and XML data from the comment